# What could I put in Key tags in my .html (LWC)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, table, key

In this table I'm using `row` as `key` for many html elements. Could this make a difference in the future?
Do I need to use a different `key` for each tag? I thought to use `row.postalcode` in the first line of the table, for example...but there may be rows with the same `row.postalcode`, `row.number` and `row.stret`.

Could I customize the keys? For example key = key + 1??

If you find another point of improvement in my code, I would be grateful for the help!

```
<template>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <!-- header -->
        </div>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover" role="listbox"
            id="lookup-grouped-table-id-1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                        <th key={col}>
                            {col}
                        </th>
                    </template>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
                        <tr key={row}>
                            <td key={row} class="slds-text-align_left">
                                <div key={row} class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <input type="radio" id={row} value={row} name="default" checked="" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td key={row}>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.postalcode}>{row.postalcode}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td key={row}>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.number}>{row.number}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td key={row}>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.street}>{row.street}</div>
                            </td>
                            <td key={row}>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.complement}>{row.complement}</div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </template></template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__footer slds-modal__footer_directional">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close">Cancel</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">New Account</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could this make a difference in the future?

Possibly. Each key must be unique, so as long as the individual rows are unique, it wouldn't necessarily matter, but you can place an object in more than once place in memory, and this could break things.

Example:

```
let value = { message: 'hello world' }
let rows = [ value, value, value ]
```

Because all three rows are the same object, this would cause an error.

> Do I need to use a different key for each tag?

The key is used to identify which element in the DOM (Document Object Model) corresponds to which object in the array. This is necessary to make certain kinds of changes as efficient as possible. Imagine, for example, you move the first element in the array to the end. Without a key, it would have to rerender the entire DOM structure, but knowing the key means the rendering system just moves the one row efficiently to the end.

As such, the key value can be anything you want it to be, but it must be a unique value. Common suggestions are a record Id or an auto-generated value, as you suggested in your question. For various reasons, it generally should not be the object itself.

So, for example, your column rendering part should look like:

```
<template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
    <th key={col.id}>
        {col.value}
    </th>
</template>
```

You don't need a key on every single element in the iteration, only the top-level element.

```
<template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
        <tr key={row.id}>
            <td class="slds-text-align_left">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <input type="radio" value={row.value} name="default" checked="" />
                </div>
...
```

As far as generating the ID values, it can be as easy as:

```
this.rows = this.rows.map((row, id) => ({...row, id}))
```

Finally, you don't need to use template tags for iterators; I prefer not to do this, as it makes things cluttered, but that's more a personal preference.

```
<tr key={row.id} for:each={rows} for:item="row">
    <td class="slds-text-align_left">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input type="radio" value={row.value} name="default" checked="" />
        </div>
...
```

You can see a more complicated [piece of code](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/QxMCNnrro9cSpcwiulBq/src/app.css?p=stories) that was prompted by an earlier question, which provides a "key = key + 1" type setup, as you've suggested.

Comment: Thanks! Is row.id generated automatically?

Comment: @Caroline No, you have to generate it yourself somehow. In the example where I call `map`, the callback actually has three parameters, `value`, `index`, and `array`, which I name the second parameter `id` so I can add it directly into the object via [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015).

Comment: Is it possible to get the index  of rows, like key = {row.index} ?

Comment: @Caroline The index itself is accessible via `for:index`, but that can't be used as the key. That's the rules. It needs to be a property of the object itself. I traditionally call my key `id`, but you can call it whatever you want.